# Checking version of GCC compiler in Code::Blocks

Tags: gcc, code-blocks

How do I check, in Code::Blocks, what version of the GCC compiler am I using?

Comment: Being primarily related to development software, this should be on [so].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `gcc --version`, the result will be something like this:

```
gcc (GCC) 4.4.0
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

If this doesn't work you might not have the compiler setup in your `PATH` correctly (I believe this is common if using MinGW on Windows), in which case you can first check where the compiler is located by doing the following within Code::Blocks:

- Menubar `Settings` -> `Compiler and Debugger`
- Select `GNU GCC Compiler`
- Select the `Toolchain executables` tab

Then, using a command line, move to the directory given, then in to the `bin` subdirectory, then try running `gcc --version` from there.

Answer (score 3):

Typically execute the command

```
gcc --version
```

and it should give you result like this:

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```